# Выравнивание элементов внутри блока по центру, но что бы последний был слева

Tags: html, css, выравнивание

У меня есть контейнер, внутри которого находятся несколько элементов, для выравнивания использую:

```
display: flex;
```

**Входные данные:**

1. Есть контейнер, внутри которого находится 5 элементов (может быть любое другое значение). Размер контейнера не фиксирован, изменяется в зависимости от изменения ширины экрана.
2. Расстояние между элементами в контейнере должно быть всегда одинаково и равняться `20px`.
3. Элементы должны располагаться по центру контейнера.
4. Последние элементы должны располагаться слева. Например, если есть 4 элемента, где 3 на первой строке, а один на второй, то последний элемент должен располагаться ровно под первым.

Я пробовал:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 400px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.inner {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
  background: #AB012D;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

В этом примере элементы расположены не по центру, а смещены влево, мне это не подходит.

Я пробовал добавить:

```
justify-content: center;
```

но тогда последние элементы располагаются по центру.

Мне нужно чтобы они смещались как можно левее, т.е. первый элемент в последней строчке расположен ровно под самым первым элементом.

Так же можно использовать:

```
justify-content: space-between;
```

но тогда расстояние между элементами изменяется, чего нельзя допустить.

Как решить такую проблему?

Необязательно использовать именно `flex`, можно любые другие технологии, главное чтобы это работало во всех более менее современных браузерах.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C [Flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/flex) можно, но достаточно заморочно. Если не требуется поддержка старых браузеров то удобнее будет воспользоваться [CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout):

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content min-content;
  justify-content: center; 
  width: 400px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.inner {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
  background: #AB012D;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

*Отдельно стоит отметить что в [Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) margin'ы не схлопываются, поэтому что бы получить 20px суммарного расстояния нужно ставить 10px, или же воспользоваться свойством [grid-gap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap).*

Comment: Да, всё как я хотел, раньше не работал с `grid` но буду учиться =)